# Jenkins not picking Chrome profile when running Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am struggling on this for days.

I installed Jenkins as Windows service and running Selenium tests by triggering Ant target. I created a Chrome profile with authentication details and using in my scripts to avoid authentication during runs. Everything works fine when I invoke Ant through command line but when I run through Jenkins script are failing at authentication. I am unable to understand why its not picking up Chrome profile rather asks for browser authentication. Please help.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\<User>\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Apple iPhone 6");
Map<String, Object> mobileOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mobileOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

mobileOptions.put("args", Arrays.asList("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\<User>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"));

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, mobileOptions);
```

Comment: Please supply your script and the relevant part(s) of the failing build's Console Log output.

Comment: Hi build has no issues. Selenium script when ran through Jenkins is not able to get pick chrome profile.  I pasted my code in original question (My Jenkins is installed running as service on windows machine)

Comment: @Praveen hi did you find a way to solve this problem?